# How to change profile url

Tags: php, .htaccess, profile

Hello I am using php and editing my .htaccess file, I am trying to make it so users can type:

website.com/users/1 which is actually website.com/profile.php?id=1

Now I find other resources that help me accomplish this but whenever I do it, it break the theme so that its nothing but a page with straight black and white content, no background color, headers, etc.

How do I accomplish this successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What .htaccess rules are you using that breaks everything?

Comment: Post your rules. You're probably missing something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and equivalent `!-d`

Comment: If you implement a rewrite as indicated in the answers below, you may run into an issue with paths for images and css if they are relative instead of absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$  profile.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /users/([^/]+)/?
RewriteRule .* http://website.com/profile.php?id=%1   [L]
```

It will map silently this:

`http://website.com/users/anything`

To:

`http://website.com/profile.php?id=anything`